# How to enable scp between two virtual machines

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, fedora

I have a windows and linux virtual machine running with virtual box. I get the ip of
windows machine. But when I do scp from linux it just halts there. Do I need to 
enable anything in windows virtual machine. I found I am not able to ping it also.

Comment: Do you have OpenSSH Server running on the Windows machine?

Comment: As @Ramhound said, you'll need to have OpenSSH Server running in the Windows virtual machine ([Installation instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)), but the inability to ping points to some type of networking configuration issue between the two VMs as well.  Will definitely need some more details there.  Starting with some basics - Can you ping the Linux VM from the Windows one?  Or does it fail in both directions?